# how to determine which JPEG picture is corrupt in Tensorflow decode_jpeg

Tags: tensorflow

when i decode JPEG format pictures, it give message "**corrupt jpeg data premature end of data segment** ". how can i determine which picture is corrupt.
This is my code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

directory = 'D:\\tfrecord\\read'
directories = []
class_names = []

photo_filenames = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    photo_filenames.append(path)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print("session")
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    for filename in photo_filenames:
        filecontents = tf.read_file(filename)
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(filecontents, channels = 3)
        try:
            sess.run(image)
        except Exception as e:
            print(filename)
            print (e)
```

Answer (score 0):

insert

```
image = tf.Print(image,[filename])
```

after

```
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(filecontents, channels = 3)
```

the filename will show right after 'corrupt jpeg data...'